# Add new tableview cells dynamically

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview

I have seen lots of posts about adding and deleting the cells in the tableview. What i want is when user clicks on add button in the cell it must ask user what to enter the text in that cell,then user enters the text in the cell and then it is added in the tableview. Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't think I understand the workflow.  You say "user clicks on add button in the cell" and also "then it is added in the tableview" but, if there's a cell that contains a button, it must already be in the table.

Comment: Yes. The add button is already present in the cell with default text. when user clicks on add button user must be able to edit the text in that particular cell.and after user enters the text in that cell another cell must be added with add button and having default text.

Answer (score 1):

I would put the add button in the footer or header, rather than in a cell, it is my personal opinion that managing the adding of cells would be easier.

Apart from this, don't know exactly what your problem is, if you make your controller as uitable delegate then you can easily add or remove cells by accessing all the relevant methods, in particular that one:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
       // ......
    }
}
```

which is called by:

```
[yourTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath ] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a method like `(UITableViewCell *) createNewCellForTableView`. This will create and return UITableViewCell.

In your `CellForRowAtIndexPath` use this method for creating all cells for your `tableView`. This needs to be done this way because when you perform a `[tableView reloadData];` it needs to create new cells each time you add a new cell.

Finally after you create new cells, in the IBAction of the `ADD` button, make sure you reload the tableView.

**~ A simpler alternative :**

Since you are just looking for the user to add text, you can have a `textField` embedded in the uitableViewcell. As soon as the user finishes typing, you can have the text added to the `dataSource` (the array populating the `tableView`) and reload the tableView. Make sure you have the textField `enabled` or `disabled` as you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it and it works:

first, create an instance variable as follows:

```
int numRows = 0;
```

Implement the method `numberOfRowsInSection` as follows:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return numRows;
}
```

Now in my application, at one place, I'm using a REST API and getting a JSON, i'm updating the value of numRows as `numRows = [jsondata count];`

Write your method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as you would want it to be if you had the dynamic content. For example in my case, I'm using the indexPath.row and preparing the cell and returning it.

This method will only be call when the variable numRows is greater than 0. So as soon as you have your dynamic content, update the content of numRows as I explained above and immediately call the method `[YourtableView reloadData];`

---